# how to check for multiple conditions

Tags: python, if-statement

I need to check if 1) x and y are numeric 2) higher than zero 3) y is greater than x. If not, display an error message at the specific condition that did not meet the requirement and end the program.

The error message don't print out at after checking condition 2 and condition 3.

```
if x.isnumeric() and y.isnumeric():
    st="both x and y are numeric"
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
    num1 = int(x)
    num2 = int(y) 
    if num1 >0 and num2 >0:
        st1 = "both x and y are greater than zero"
    else:
        print("One or more of your inputs are not greater than zero!")
    if num2 > num1:
        st2 = "y greater than x"
    else:
        print("You did not enter a value of y that is greater than x")
```

The output that I can get is

Please enter the value of x: 3
Please enter the value of y: 2

No error message is shown.

Comment: Can you be more specific as to the problem?  For example, give example input, what result you expect & what you get instead.

Comment: When you test this code, what are the values of `x` and `y`?  What result do you observe?  What result did you expect?  Why?

Comment: Double check the indentation, if looks like the latter part of the code should be unindented or part of the first `if` block

Comment: If multiple conditions are not mutually exclusive you may need separate `if` for each of them.

Comment: @PM77-1, can you further elaborate on separate if?

Comment: @mozway, which latter part of the code, which part are you referring to? this part -  if num1 >0 and num2 >0:?

Comment: Posted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77454154/2055998) shows this approach.

Comment: @unleasehed everything after the second `if` since these require valid numbers

Comment: @mozway, meaning i need to indent inside the first if for the second and third condition?

Comment: If the *isnumeric()* test returns True, you will not necessarily be able to convert the string to *int*

Answer (score 2):

Basic logic: return early if a condition is not met, with the error.

```py
def validate(x, y):
    # try converting the x and y values to ints
    try:
        x = int(x)
        y = int(y)
    # if can't, return early
    except:
        return "One or more of your inputs are not numeric!"

    # condition 2
    if not (x > 0 and y > 0):
        return "One or more of your inputs are not greater than zero!"

    # condition 3
    if not (y > x):
        return "You did not enter a value of y that is greater than x"

    # return nothing to show all is fine
    return


# take the inputs
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")
# get the error (if any)
error = validate(x, y)
if error:
    print(error)
```

Another solution, building up on your code:

```py
x = input("Please enter the value of x: ")
y = input("Please enter the value of y: ")

if (
    (x.startswith("-") and x[1:].isnumeric())
    or x.isnumeric()
    and (y.startswith("-") and y[1:].isnumeric())
    or y.isnumeric()
):
    num1 = int(x)
    num2 = int(y)
    if num1 > 0 and num2 > 0:
        if num2 > num1:
            st2 = "y greater than x"
        else:
            print("You did not enter a value of y that is greater than x")
    else:
        print("One or more of your inputs are not greater than zero!")
else:
    print("One or more of your inputs are not numeric!")
```

PS: Check the comments below, there are cases where `isnumeric()` will return true, but converting to `int()` will error.

Comment: Thank you. I need to ensure condition 1 is met before moving on to condition 2 and condition 2 is met before moving on to condition 3. Eg: If condition 2 is not met, i need to print out the error message and end the program.

Comment: I have updated the solution!

Comment: Thank you for your help, is it possible to do it via if else loop? I have yet to learn the syntax that you have provided.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @slothrop! I have fixed the code.

Comment: Cool, that looks like it works. You could also do `x.removeprefix('-').isnumeric()` in Python>=3.9.

Comment: Trying to convert the string to int and handling any exception is the superior approach. For example "4²".isnumeric() == True yet int("4²") will raise a ValueError exception